# Which is best data structure for searching and counting of pairs of objects in vector of vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set, std-pair

I have defined `class element` and `class node`  .

**class element**

```
class element
{
    int id;
    std::vector<node> m_nodes;   // An element consist of 4 nodes.
    public:
    getnode(int)    // return n-th node;       
}
```

**class node**

```
class node
{
    int id;
    // other members
}
```

The `class model` consist of entire `node` and `element` objects.      `class element` object consist of vector of four `node` objects. A pair of two consecutive (adjacent) `node` objects is called face.

**Example:**
elem1  : { 1,2,3,4 }
elem2  :  { 3,5,6,4 }
elem1 and elem2 are two `element` objects and integers in array represent ids of four node objects.
1-2, 2-3, 3-4, and 4-1 are faces of elem1. and 3-5, 5-6, 6-4 and 4-3 are faces of elem2. *face 3-4 and face 4-3 are identical and hence shared by both elements*.

A boundary element is the element which consist of at least one face, which is not shared by other elements. In the above example, both elem1 and elem2 are boundary elements. A vector of boundary elements is also defined in the model class.

**class model**

```
class model    
{    
    std::vector<node> m_nodes;
    std::vector<element>m_elements;
    std::vector<element>m_boundary;

    public:
    void set_boundary_elements();
}
```

**PROBLEM: How to initialise vector of boundary elements**
This is the pseudo code of the set_boundary_elements() function.

```
void model::set_boundary_elements()
{
     std::vector <std::pair<std::set<int> , int >> faces;
     std::set<int> s;
     for(auto iter::m_elements)
     {
         //initialise  face.
         for(int i=1; i<5; ++i)
         {
             if(i != 4)
              {
                  s.insert(iter.getnode(i));
                  s.insert(iter.getnode(i+1));
              }
              else 
              {
                  s.insert(iter.getnode(4));s.insert(iter.getnode(1));   
              }
              for(auto it: faces)
              {
                  if(s== it.first)
                       (it.second)++; break;
              }
              faces.push_back(s,1);
         }
         //then push_back the elements which have nonshared faces, into m_boundary.
     }
}
```

I think my algorithm is inefficient since for adding a face each time I have to iterate through all faces. Is there any useful method in stl/algorithm to solve my problem efficiently?

Comment: As an aside, if you're guaranteed that a `element` only ever has 4 `node` instances, then a `std::array` might be a better choice than a `std::vector`.

Comment: So it sounds like you have a graph, conceptually. You may want to re-think your model depending on how important some computations are. An element is really a subgraph that could be represented with an adjacency list. Finding boundary elements would consist of subtracting the union of all other sets from some set i. . I don't know if any of this helps you, but perhaps rethinking the design from set and graph theory may aid you.

Comment: As said before, use std::array for static sized vectors and use const  references in your for loops:
for (const auto &iter: m_elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rethink your design. Currently, elements do not really share nodes. Two elements which should share a node simply each store a different set of data that happens to have the same id. Which means that if something changes one node, the system might be inconsistent.

Here is my proposal (without constructors, getters, setters et cetera, assuming that you can fill in those easily):

```
class Model {

    class Node;
    class Element;

private:

    vector<Node> nodes;
    vector<Element> elements;

}

class Model::Element {
private:
    Element(); //only to be created by Model
    vector<unsigned int> incident_nodes;
}

class Model::Node {
private:
    Node(); //only to be created by Model
    vector<unsigned int> incident_elements;
}
```

Note that both Node and Element store incident items, and they do so with **integers** that reference their id within the vectors in Model. Model is responsible for creating and modifying Nodes and Elements, and such methods will be responsible to leave the data consistently. All public methods on Element or Node are constant.

This leaves you with a stable system that has references in both directions. If you want to know if an Element is on the boundary, the code is

```
//returns all entries that are in both vectors
inline vector<unsigned int> intersection(const vector<unsigned int>& vector_a,
    const vector<unsigned int>& vector_b);

typedef vector<unsigned int> Face; //defined in model, a pair of node ids

//number = 0..3, returns the corresponding face
Model::Face Model::get_face(const unsigned int element_id,
    const unsigned int number);

vector<unsigned int> Model::incident_elements(const Face& face){
    return intersection(nodes[face[0]].incident_elements,
        nodes[face[1]].incident_elements);
}

bool Model::is_boundary(const unsigned int element_id){

    //check if it has a face that is boundary
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<4;i++){
        Face face = get_face(element_id, i); 
        if(incident_elements(face).size() == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(all referenced methods and functions should be self-explanatory, Face could be converted into a struct or class, maybe with a method Face::incident_elements{return intersection(...);}, especially if you want to do more stuff on faces, but probably with Face objects to be temporary since they can be easily extracted)

This way allows you clean operations, although of course every node needs to store the incident element vector, which requires more memory. But I doubt that you will be able to work efficiently without something like that, especially since I assume that you will want to do more of such operations.

One could replace the vectors in Node and Element by something of static size, but I don't consider this that big of a deal, especially since they can only be accessed within Model.

Downside of the architecture is that deletion is either inefficient (change all id storages) or leaves holes in the memory (although that is not too bad if a list of unused ids is stored)

Answer (score 3):

As said in a comment to your post, use std::array for static sized vectors and use const references in your for loops, that will avoid copies and help optimization:

```
 for (const auto &iter: m_elements)
```

and

```
 for(auto &it: faces)
```

If you have a lot of elements (> 50) I think you should also change the container used for faces from **std::vector** to **std::map**, so that this:

```
          for(auto it: faces)
          {
              if(s== it.first)
                   (it.second)++; break;
          }
          faces.push_back(s,1);
```

will become:

```
         auto &it = faces.find(s);
         if (it != faces.end())
             it.second++;
         else
             faces.insert(std::make_pair(s, 1));
```